из главного скрипта python нужно включать и выключать другой скрипт
from project import script2 as scr2

scr2.main()

Эта команда включает скрипт, есть ли команда чтобы она его завершала?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Данным кодом:
from project import script2 as scr2
scr2.main()

вы просто делаете обычный импорт модуля и обычный вызов функции. Функция будет выполнятся до своего завершения либо аварийного выхода с ошибкой, и тут нет какой-то возможности управлять выполнением этой функцией "снаружи" - из первого скрипта, так как "снаружи" никакого кода не выполняется - вы передали управление во второй скрипт.
Возможно то что вы ищете - это запуск второго скрипта в отдельном потоке или процессе, которым можно будет управлять например через threading.Event.
